# Message Decoding/Encrypting Program output JAVA

Tags: java

I am very confused about something that the program I wrote is outputting. The purpose of the program is to decode/encode to a type of code called Caesar Shift, which basically just takes each letter of a word/sentence and shifts it to the right by a "shift key". (ex. ab with shift key 1 = bc).

I have the program set up so that it asks the user for either Encryption/Decryption, then the message that they want to either encode/decode, then the shift key. I am having the same problem with both my functions for encoding/decoding. I will focus on the encoding one for this question, since they are pretty much the same.

Basically, I have the encoding function set up so that  it takes parameters of a String message and an int ShiftKey. I have a String array of each individual letter of the message. My plan is to go through each letter in the array/word, find it's current index in the alphabet, and add the shift Key to it, which is stored in int finalIndex. I append the letter of the alphabet at index finalIndex, and finally print ot the word.

```
public static void encode(String message, int shiftKey)
{
    String [] array = message.split("");
    String encoded = "";
    for (String a : array)
    {
        int finalIndex;
        int index = alphabet.indexOf(a);
        finalIndex = index + shiftKey;
        encoded += alphabet.charAt(finalIndex);
    }
    System.out.println(encoded);
}
```

The problem is that when I run the program, the output is right, except for that at the beginning of the encoded phrase, there is always an extra letter that is the index of the alphabet at the shiftKey.
For example, if I type the message "hi", with shift key 1, then it outputs "bij", because b is the alphabet at index 1, and hi is just the expected shift.

I have tried everything, but I cannot figure out why this is happening. I'm sure it is a problem with this function, and not anywhere else because I tried isolating different areas to see where the problem was.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Full Code**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CaesarShiftTester
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    boolean running = true;
    while (running){
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Encryption or Decryption? (E/D): " );
        String answer = in.next();

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter message: ");
        String message = in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Shift Key: " );
        int shiftKey = in.nextInt(); 
        CaesarShiftEncryption.encode(message, shiftKey);

        System.out.println("Quit? (Y/N): ");
        String again = in.next();
        if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            running = false;
        else
            running = true;
    }

    else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter message: ");
        String message = in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Shift Key: " );
        int shiftKey = in.nextInt();
        CaesarShiftEncryption.decode(message, shiftKey);

        System.out.println("Quit? (Y/N): ");
        String again = in.next();
        if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                running = false;
        else
            running = true;
    }
    }


}
}
```

\

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CaesarShiftEncryption
{
private static final String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
public static void encode(String message, int shiftKey)
{
    String [] array = message.split("");

    String encoded = "";
    for (String a : array)
    {
        System.out.println(a);

        int finalIndex;
        int index = alphabet.indexOf(a);
        finalIndex = index + shiftKey;
        System.out.println(finalIndex);
        encoded += alphabet.charAt(finalIndex);
    }
    System.out.println(encoded);
}


public static void decode(String message, int shiftKey)
{
    char shifted;
    String encoded = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i ++)
    {
        char nextChar = message.charAt(i);
        shifted = (char)(nextChar - shiftKey);
        encoded += shifted;
    }
    System.out.println("Encoded: " + encoded);  
 } 
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: When I print out the contents of array, the output is fine, it prints each letter of message as it should, but when I print out the final indexes, it prints out the shiftkey, and then the correct final Indexes, so it is one more than it should be.

Comment: I tested you code, it is working as it should. you probably have a problem with the message

Comment: I added the full code in case it might be any help

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem... if I type in "hi" with key 1 I get "ij"...

Comment: Your code worked for me, I didn't see any extra letters...  Here's the output: Encryption or Decryption? (E/D): 
e
Enter message: 
hi
Enter Shift Key: 
1
h
8
i
9
ij

Comment: dude, your code worked here too.

Comment: This is very strange....I have the exact same code as posted above but when I do it it outputs "bij", not "ij". Could it be a problem with the compiler? I'm using BlueJ because this is for a school assignment and that is what the course uses, but I'm going to try it on Eclipse as soon as it downloads.

Comment: I would not put blueJ as the most reliable IDE, but eclipce and blueJ will use the same JDK, on you machine..I dont think this is the problem.

Comment: I actually tried it on Eclipse and weirdly it worked, but I will update to jdk8 for future issues. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK problem.

Consider using JDK 8..

On JDK 7 split function puts an extra element on the beginning if you do split("").

If you can't update, you might use char[], or just skip the first one(change the enhanced for loop to a conventional one)

I tested your code and it was working fine.. that is why was so confusing..then I changed the JDK to version 7, and got the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1):

The problems is your use of `message.split("")` function. It adds an empty element into the array.

Following code works.

```
public class test {

  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    char[] array = "ab".toCharArray();
    String alphabet = "abc";
    String encoded = "";
    int shiftKey = 1;

    for (char a : array)
    {
        int finalIndex;
        int index = alphabet.indexOf(a);
        finalIndex = index + shiftKey;
        encoded += alphabet.charAt(finalIndex);
    }

    System.out.println(encoded);
  }    
}
```

Also use of toCartArray() method is more appropriate for this use case.

Comment: Downvote (not mine) was given when your post was code-only. Also, you should rewrite this to be the `encode` method rather than the `main` method, and preferably say something about your use of toCharArray.

Comment: The down vote is not mine, but I tough about that and is not true

Comment: I have run the code and tested. So what do you mean not true? you thought, I have run the code

Comment: do you think it could be the JDK? I am using oracle's and you?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I found, it is JDK thing. you are correct if using the JDK you are using.. I gonna up vote you, but the original down vote was not mine..

Comment: Thanks Victor. Glad we collectively found this. Interesting :)

Comment: it is always better when we can discuss like that, stack overflow needs more of this instead of ego fights. that was interesting